# Access sub sub category, Shopware, Smarty

Tags: smarty, shopware

trying to solve issue with sub sub category access in Shopware with smarty, but not sure at all how to do it. Maybe someone knows.

```html
<!-- THIS WORKS -->

{if $Category.sub}
  {foreach $Category.sub as $sub}
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span itemprop="name">{$sub.name}</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {/foreach}
{/if}

<!-- THIS DOESN'T WORK -->
{if $Category.sub.sub}
  {foreach $Category.sub.sub as $subsub}
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span itemprop="name">{$subsub.name}</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {/foreach}
{/if}
```

Comment: Post the data you [`assign()`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.assign.tpl) to `$Category`.

Comment: not sure how :(
{if $Category.sub.sub}
   {assign var="subsub" value=$Category.sub.sub}
      <li>
         <a href="#">
            <span itemprop="name">{$subsub.name}</span>
         </a>
      </li>
{/if}

Comment: Use [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) with the value you `assign()` to `$Category` then view the source of the web page in the browser and copy-paste the output of `print_r()` into the question. Use only a relavant fragment of it if it is too large.

Comment: {$Category.sub[0]['sub']}

Comment: @AlexeyPalamar - that is what I need :) thanks - and maybe do U know how to access like the sub > sub.name :) not as array, I tried something like  
{$Category.sub[0]['sub.name']} but without success :/

Comment: {foreach $Category.sub[0][sub] as $subsub}
     <p>{$subsub.name}</p>
{/foreach}   That doesn't work :(

Comment: @if.cookie, check my answer, hope it's what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check example above:

```
{foreach $Category.sub as $categoryItem}
    {foreach $categoryItem.sub as $subsub}
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span itemprop="name">{$subsub.name}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Advanced example:

```
{foreach $Category.sub as $number => $categoryItem}
    {if $categoryItem.childrenCount}
        <ul id="submenu-{$number}" {if $categoryItem.flag}class="is--active"{/if}>
            {if $categoryItem.cmsHeadline}
                <li class="menu--list-item item--level-1">
                    <span class="menu--list-item-title">{$categoryItem.cmsHeadline}</span>
                </li>
            {/if}
            {foreach $categoryItem.sub as $subcategory}
                {if $subcategory.hideTop}
                    {continue}
                {/if}

                {$categoryLink = $subcategory.link}
                {if $subcategory.external}
                    {$categoryLink = $subcategory.external}
                {/if}

                <li class="menu--list-item item--level-1{if $subcategory.flag} item--is-active{/if}">
                    <a href="{$categoryLink|escapeHtml}" class="menu--list-item-link" title="{$subcategory.name|escape}">{$subcategory.name}</a>
                </li>
            {/foreach}
        </ul>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```